How could I find the maximum speed of a swinging object through graphing its path
I'm thinking of using a video of a tennis swing and putting it into a graphing software to trace out its path and find its maximum velocity.
How would I go about doing this?
Variable dependent on the camera (Focal length, frame rate etc) shouldn't be accounted for, I just want to find the maximum speed of its journey.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Just plotting the path is not enough to get the velocity. You can move along a given path with any velocity you want, including varying it in any way. Say I move in a straight line from A to B. I can start with some $v_1$, stop, reverse a little bit, then continue. This will have the same graph as if I started with $v_2$ and continuously slow down, such that you get $0$ velocity at B. So what you want is position as a function of time (or frame number). Then look at the largest change between steps.

@Andrei The object is going to swing in a straight line in a constant direction. Does this help?

No. That's what I was trying to explain. You can move in a straight line at a constant velocity, accelerating, decelerating, or a combination of these. You need something that depends on time, like frame number

Can I trace the path of the object by plotting a dot frame by frame? is this what you're talking about
